# Start activity is slow

Tags: android, android-activity, android-asynctask

I'm write a music application online.But i'm meet a problem... A new activity starts slowly when I select an item in listview...
I don't know resolve, please help me ! :(
Sorry. I'm speak English very bad :(

This is my code:

```
public class startNewActivity extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
    private Activity activity;
    private String selectDoc = "div.gen img";
    private String attr = "title";
    private String result;
    public String Quality;

    public startNewActivity(Activity activity) {
        this.activity = activity;
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... arg0) {
        nameSong = (String) lvSong.getItemAtPosition(positionId);
        link = linkSong.get(Integer.valueOf(obj.toString()));

        Quality = Utils.getQuality(link, selectDoc, attr, result);
        Log.i("Quality", Quality);
        changeLink = link.replace(".html", "_download.html").substring(15)
                .replaceFirst("", "http://download")
                .replace("nhac-hot", "mp3".concat("/vietnam/v-pop"));
        Log.i("Change link", changeLink);
        try {
          //Connect internet
            linkIntent = Utils.getLinkPlay(selectLinkPlay, changeLink,
                    afterChangeLink);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "Server has problem... Please while for minutes",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        return linkIntent;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
     //i'm want help here
        Intent i = new Intent(SongActivity.this, PlayMusicActivity.class);
        i.putExtra("song", linkIntent);
        i.putExtra("namesong", nameSong);
        i.putExtra("Quality", Quality);
        i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        activity.startActivity(i);
        pDialog.dismiss();
        super.onPostExecute(result);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        pDialog = ProgressDialog.show(SongActivity.this, "",
                "Please wait...");
    }
}
```

Comment: Use Traceview to determine where your time is being spent.

Comment: what code hv u writeen onClick? plz post that

Comment: @CommonsWare I'm newbie :(. But the activity start when click about 3-4s

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're starting the new activity inside `onPostExecute()` which executes only after you've completed `doInBackground()`. Hence, the time delay.

Ideally, you should start the activity just after you execute your AsyncTask. The AsyncTask will continue in the background while your activity changes.

Comment: First... I'm tks you reply my question... i'm will edit my code

Comment: Now.I'm start PlayMusicActivity and Process it before Play